# Google Chrome web inspector broken?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm using Chromes web inspector quite a while, but since version 26~28 (since Chrome have a new "style", like the full width autocomplete field below the search bar or the removed icons in the web inspector) the web inspector seems to be broken.

Every time I try to look at the source code (at the Resources tab), it only shows the javascripts and nothing else:

[image]

I removed all Chrome files from my Mac (even the Cache folder and so on in the ~/Library folder) and reinstalled Chromed, but this doesn't helped.

Only solution that worked for me: using an old version (21)...

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to work okay for me on version 30

Comment: This screenshot was taken with Chrome 30

Comment: Is there nothing under Images, Scripts, and Stylesheets?

Comment: For sure there are files, but why should this belongs to my question/problem? I want to see the whole source code of the site and the screenshots shows clearly a bug (or am I wrong?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be this bug: [crbug.com/252194](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=252194).

Comment: Seems to be. I tried Chrome Canary (32) and there, I don't even see Javascripts but only an empty document (like the screenshot here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=252194)